# Posting to a complex typed array

Tags: odata, abap, sap-gateway

I have an ORDER structure in ABAP that has another ITEMS structure within it which will contain multiple items per order.

I'm populating this structure through a SAP Gateway service, which works for an ORDER + a single ITEM.

```
{
  "d": {
    "Venueid": "dsfgg",
    "Items" : {
    "__metadata" : {
      "type" : "ZGW_XXXX_SRV.Items"},
      "Venueid" : "dsd",
      "Type" : ""
      }
   }
 }
```

However, what would be the syntax to provide an array of more than one ITEM?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was because multiples can only be handled with the DEEP_INSERT method, not the normal CREATE.